# Automatic repair of eslint is invalid

Tags: eslint, vue-cli-3

I configure rules that do not allow semicolons, but `eslint -- fix'does not automatically fix it?

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "semi": ["error", "never"]
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  }
```

console output：

```sh
PS D:\web\items\cnode-m> npx eslint --fix .\src\main.js

D:\web\items\cnode-m\src\main.js
   1:22  error  Extra semicolon  semi
   2:28  error  Extra semicolon  semi
   3:30  error  Extra semicolon  semi
   4:28  error  Extra semicolon  semi
   6:33  error  Extra semicolon  semi
  12:18  error  Extra semicolon  semi

✖ 6 problems (6 errors, 0 warnings)
  6 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It's `@vue/prettier`. I uninstalled this and replaced it with `@vue/standard'.`